# Column isn't being found?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the username, last name, join date and country name for all the users who joined after the 13th January 2017 in ascending order. However each time I try to call any column, I get the error message "Column: Invalid Identifier".

```
SELECT Username, LastName, JoinDate, CountryName
FROM BR_USER, BR_COUNTRY
WHERE JoinDate = '01-JAN-17' AND JoinDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY JoinDate ASC;
```

Here is an image of how the BR_USER table is created. 
[image]

Simple codes like:

```
SELECT UserId
FROM BR_USER;
```

Gives the same invalid identifier error, help

Comment: Do not use double quotes around identifiers when they are defined.  When you do, you need to enclose them in double quotes when they are used -- and that just clutters code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh I see, I need to use double quotes when calling the columns, thank you so much, what  a dumb mistake.

Comment: . . Or better yet, don't use double quotes when defining them.

Comment: Also, double quotes around uppercase names are pointless and risk hiding errors, e.g. if you accidentally named a table `"BR USER"` when you meant `BR_USER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) explains:

> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

If you define a column name with double quotes, you are condemned to using the double quotes whenever your reference that column.  Or table or anything else with a name.

Actually, I don't think the documentation is 100% correct.  Oracle uppercases all identifiers for resolution.  So, if you define a quoted identifier with all upper case, then it will work without quotes.  So this works:

```
create table t (
    "COL" int
);

select "COL", COL, col
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5850f6dd4bdb9a6a860ae5843596f2e6) is a db<>fiddle.

But who wants to remember such rules -- rules so arcane and complex that the documentation is even misleading.

Simple solution:  Don't use double quotes.